# Feature engineering: Best way to feed a 360° orientation variable into a neural network

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

A predictor (X) variable could be an orientation variable on a 360° scale.

Obviously, it is a continuum, the value 360 being very close to 1. Inputing a continuous variable from 1 to 360 into the neural network would thus introduce bias.

What would be the best way to handle this ?

- One way could be to categorizing the values (1 to 360) into categories: North - NorthEast - East - EastSouth - South - SouthWest - West - WestNorth.

Any other suggestions or comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By expressing your feature as 2 dimensions, instead of one you can easily avoid this problem - simply push it through cosine and sine, this way you change your angle into a point on a unit circle.

```
f(a) := [cos(a), sin(a)]
```

Note that we now have `f(0) = f(2*pi) = f(4 * pi)` and so on. Note that this is in radians, if you are using degrees you want to do instead

```
g(d) := f(d/180 * pi)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot, to make sure I understand correctly: In a first step, the degrees are converted into radians. In a second step one new feature being the cos() of the radian values is created and another new feature being the sin() of the radian values is created as well. Finally, the network will process both of these new features. Correct ?

Comment: That's correct. It is a way to project your angle onto points of the unit circle. I recommend you plot this transformation, take various angles and plot in 2d what it does to better understand it.